# How to save images to a external folder at the same time

Tags: interface, file-browser

I usually have a lot of images due to texture baking and stuff and I need to save them to a folder just in case I lose them due to a crash but I hate doing it one at a time. Is there a way of saving multiple/all images to a folder at once?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:
[image]

Note, though: This will save all images to a default folder (did not test, but it's probably the one that you specify in Edit -> Preferences -> Filepaths -> Textures).
Mine is // (default) which means all images that were created inside Blender will be in the same folder as the .blend
fill in //Textures to save them in a subdir named Textures

Comment: Definitely works. But There’s a small issue. When I moved the files to my desired directory and save the blend file and has an issue with autopack saying: “cannot pack file. Source path [FILE DIRECTORY] not found. Should I just turn off auto pack?

Comment: If you move a .blend, it's directories don't get updated, so if they are absolute (C:\Blender\myblend\textures\diffuse.png) will still work. 
If the path is '//textures\diffuse.png', moving the .blend and the textures folder at the same time should not break anything, but if you move the .blend, but not the textures folder, the error occurs.
turning off autopack should solve the issue, but make sure the images still open in the image editor